# Symfony 3 Twig Bootstrap style not rendering properly in form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, twig, symfony-3.4

I followed the form collections tutorial from the official documentation, it's working, then i tried to add some css using bootstrap, the thing is, it's displaying the inputs like this:
[image]

i added the form-control class in the setDefaults

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Tag::class,
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ),
    ]);
}
```

this is the twig file where the form is rendered

```
<h3>Task</h3>
    {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}
        {{ form_row(form.descripcion, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        <h3>Tags</h3>

        <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.tags.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}">
            {% for tags in form.tags %}
                <li>{{ form_row(tags.name) }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Edit: this is the generated data-prototype

```
<ul class="tags" data-prototype="&lt;div&#x20;id&#x3D;&quot;task_tags___name__&quot;&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;form-control&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label&#x20;for&#x3D;&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot;&#x20;class&#x3D;&quot;required&quot;&gt;Name&lt;&#x2F;label&gt;&lt;input&#x20;type&#x3D;&quot;text&quot;&#x20;id&#x3D;&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot;&#x20;name&#x3D;&quot;task&#x5B;tags&#x5D;&#x5B;__name__&#x5D;&#x5B;name&#x5D;&quot;&#x20;required&#x3D;&quot;required&quot;&#x20;maxlength&#x3D;&quot;255&quot;&#x20;&#x2F;&gt;&lt;&#x2F;div&gt;&lt;&#x2F;div&gt;"></ul>
```

so, what am i doing wrong? if any other part of the code is needed, let me know, thanks

Comment: Open generated html of your form, probably something is incorrect with `data-prototype` attribute.

Comment: in the cache folder or right click - > source code??

Comment: *Second* option.

Comment: i added the generated data-prototype, can you see anything weird?